# Saving a string serialized and buffered android JAVA.IO ObjectInputStream

Tags: android, save, java-io

I am saving out and loading mixed data types. I either have the saving part wrong or the loading part wrong. I am using buffered serial save and load method. 
Variable lastFetchDate is defined as a string and initialized as "00/00/00".
It throws an error when reloading the data after it has been saved. What is wrong? I would have thought the opposite to writeBytes would be readBytes for a string.

Saving is as follows:

```
  FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream("userPrefs.dat"); 
  BufferedOutputStream bos = new BufferedOutputStream(fos);   
  ObjectOutputStream oos = new ObjectOutputStream(bos);
  oos.writeBytes(lastFetchDate);
  // I close all streams
```

Loading is as follows:

```
  FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream("userPrefs.dat"); 
  BufferedInputStream bis = new BufferedInputStream(fis);   
  ObjectInputStream ois = new ObjectInputStream(bis);
  lastFetchDate=(String)ois.readObject();  //<<<<< Error thrown here
  // I close all streams
```

Comment: you have written string as byte[] so need to read as byte[] you will have to use http://developer.android.com/reference/java/io/ObjectInputStream.html#readFully(byte[], int, int)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have written string as byte[] so need to read as byte[]

```
    byte [] bString = new byte[lastFetchDate.length()*2];
    ois.readFully(bString, 0, bString.length);
```

Or if you write as Object using [writeObject method](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/io/ObjectOutputStream.html#writeObject%28java.lang.Object%29)  then you can read as object,

```
oos.writeObject(lastFetchDate);
```